# Gradient colored datatable rows in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

In R's Shiny, can I make something like this
[example](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html), but where negative values are given a different color, and plotted using their absolute value for bar length?

```
# using styleColorBar
datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(names(df),
  background = styleColorBar(range(df), 'lightblue'),
  backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
  backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
  backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it manually using `rowCallback`

as you can see

```
sss=datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(names(df),
                              background = styleColorBar(range(df), 'lightblue'),
                              backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                              backgroundPosition = 'center')


sss$x$options$rowCallback
```

Generate for each column :

> function(row, data) { var value=data[ 1]; if (value!==null)
>   $(this.api().cell(row,
>   1).node()).css({'background':isNaN(parseFloat(value)) || value <=
>   -1.311 ? '' : 'linear-gradient(90deg, transparent ' + (2.199 - value)/3.51 * 100 + '%, lightblue ' + (2.199 - value)/3.51 * 100 +
>   '%)','background-size':'98%
>   88%','background-repeat':'no-repeat','background-position':'center'});

So :

1) You need to calc range variables:

```
rr=range(df)[2]-range(df)[1]
r1=range(df)[2]
r0=range(df)[1]
```

2) Than use it in `rowCallback`

```
  datatable(
  df,  
  options = list(
        rowCallback=JS(paste0("function(row, data) {",
                              paste(lapply(1:ncol(df),function(i){
                                paste0("var value=data[",i,"];
                                       if (value!==null){
                                       if(value<0){
                                       $(this.api().cell(row,",i,").node()).css({'background':isNaN(parseFloat(value)) || value <=",r0," ? '' : 'linear-gradient(90deg, transparent ' + (",r1," - value)/",rr," * 100 + '%, red ' + (",r1," - value)/",rr," * 100 + '%)','background-size':'98% 88%','background-repeat':'no-repeat','background-position':'center'});
                                       }else{
                                       $(this.api().cell(row,",i,").node()).css({'background':isNaN(parseFloat(value)) || value <=",r0," ? '' : 'linear-gradient(90deg, transparent ' + (",r1," - value)/",rr," * 100 + '%, lightblue ' + (",r1," - value)/",rr," * 100 + '%)','background-size':'98% 88%','background-repeat':'no-repeat','background-position':'center'});
                                       }
                                       } ") 
}),collapse="\n"),
"}"))
  )
)
```

Here I hard coded colors (red and lightblue)

Result 
[image]

If you want different length for positive and negative you need different range variable or using `abs`\ `Math.abs` - for absolute value (for var in JS and for ranges)

## Ps

Numeration for columns in JS started from 0 so if you havent rownames you need `0:(ncol(df)-1)` in `lapply` for right result

## Update

Range -1 :1 and color scale for abs value

```
df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(runif(50, -1, 1), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))


rr=range(abs(df))[2]-range(abs(df))[1]
r1=range(abs(df))[2]
r0=range(abs(df))[1]



datatable(
  df,  
  options = list(
        rowCallback=JS(paste0("function(row, data) {",
                              paste(lapply(1:ncol(df),function(i){
                                paste0("var value=Math.abs(data[",i,"]);
                                        var value2=data[",i,"];
                                       if (value!==null){
                                       if(value2<0){
                                       $(this.api().cell(row,",i,").node()).css({'background':isNaN(parseFloat(value)) || value <=",r0," ? '' : 'linear-gradient(90deg, transparent ' + (",r1," - value)/",rr," * 100 + '%, red ' + (",r1," - value)/",rr," * 100 + '%)','background-size':'98% 88%','background-repeat':'no-repeat','background-position':'center'});
                                       }else{
                                       $(this.api().cell(row,",i,").node()).css({'background':isNaN(parseFloat(value)) || value <=",r0," ? '' : 'linear-gradient(90deg, transparent ' + (",r1," - value)/",rr," * 100 + '%, lightblue ' + (",r1," - value)/",rr," * 100 + '%)','background-size':'98% 88%','background-repeat':'no-repeat','background-position':'center'});
                                       }
                                       } ") 
}),collapse="\n"),
"}"))
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: I was wondering if you have an idea and if you have the time, if it is possible to scale the color gradiently. Like my dataframe will be values between -1 and 1, so is it possible to make 0.0 transparent -> 0.5 mid-transparent-red -> 1.0 full-red but with a continuous scale not by doing multiple conditions on the value

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see, yeah it's just perfect now thanks a lot ! you made my day :)